# Debugging gist-vim

Tags: github, vim, gist

I am using https://github.com/mattn/gist-vim and installing it as a submodule with vim pathogen in my bundle directory.

I have also set

```
git config --global github.user calvinchengx
git config --global github.token [mysecrettoken]
```

I am able to get commands such as `Gist -l` working fine, with this command retrieving a list of gists belong to me.  I can also preview other coders' gists with `Gist -l [thegithubusername]` with no problems.

But I am unable to post a new gist to github. When attempting to post a new gist, I get the following error:

```
Posting it to gist...
Post failed:
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

There isn't any useful error message shown.  So I am not exactly what the problem is.  Is there a way to find out what my error is (not familiar with debugging vim scripts)?

Appreciate any suggestions!

I tried setting up again after pulling the latest gist-vim but this is the error I get:-

[image: error setting up gist-vim credentials]

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I have my github token set in `.gitconfig`, also tried setting it via `let g:github_token`. I can definitely list my public gists, not the private ones.

Comment: The `Unknown function: webapi#…` seems to indicate that you have not installed/upgraded the [webapi plugin](https://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim) mentioned in the README/help (under “requirements”).

Comment: I do have that, Chris.

I installed it via `git submodule add git://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim.git bundles/webapi-api` as I am using pathogen to manage all vim plugins.

Comment: I think I made a mistake with the path to webapi-vim, which is why it screwed up. Corrected it and `:Gist -p` works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Github has deprecated the v2 of the API where gist creation was made by posting to gist.github.com, now in v3 it has to be done through api.github.com instead, probably some other differences to.

Api docs: http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Similar issue: https://github.com/defunkt/gist/issues/79

Comment: looks like a good place to start. thanks for the tip-off. will give this a shot and report back.

Answer (score 2):

Use new gist.vim. If you are using git command, pull master branch.
This include some changes breaking spec. new one don't use github_token. You'll need to setup for instruction to choose basic auth or oauth2. please read README or `:help gist-vim`.

Comment: updated the gist-vim but I am still having some errors. See screenshot above. Any idea why?

Comment: @calvin-cheng
* Do you install git?
* Do you install curl?
* Did you upgrade webapi-vim too?
* Are you using proxy?

Comment: I made a mistake setting up `webapi-vim` under `pathogen`. My bad. Problem solved and working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I've got same error, install WebAPI.vim plugin solve problem

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4019